# How to use Python functions in Mathematica functions in Python notebooks?

Tags: plotting, python

I want to plot things with Mathematica, inside an ipynb Python notebook. I can easily plot functions that are expressed in the Wolfram Language, e.g. with

```py
from wolframclient.evaluation import WolframLanguageSession
from wolframclient.language import wlexpr, wl
from PIL import Image
import io

with WolframLanguageSession() as session:
    plot = session.evaluate(wlexpr('Plot[Sin[x], {x,0, Pi}]'))
    img_data = session.evaluate(wl.ExportByteArray(plot, 'PNG'))
    img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(img_data))
img
```

but what I really want to do is to plot certain outputs of my machine learning model. Let's say I wrap that into some python function like

```py
def compute_something(x: float, y: float) -> float:
    # ...
```

and now I want to create a `ContourPlot` of this function. Something like this:

```py
session.evaluate(wlexpr(
    'ContourPlot[computeSomething[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]'
))
```

But how do I pass the numeric python function `compute_something` to the `session` so it is represented as `computeSomething` in Mathematica? Remember that I am in an iPython notebook with some Python kernel already running and holding this function.

(P.S.: I really really don't want to use matplotlib.)

Comment: I suspect something like `computeSomething = ExternalFunction[session, "compute_something"]` should work, but what is the `session` here, when I started the Mathematica Kernel from Python?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming we have a sample function in python:

```python
def computeSomething(x,y):
    return x+y
```

Here are three possible solutions:

### 1 - Easiest

Generate data points in Python, export the table, and use `ListContourPlot` (assuming you have [`numpy`](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/)):

**In Python**

```python
import numpy as np

# generate a table
data=[[x,y,computeSomething(x,y)] for x in np.arange(0,1,.2) for y in np.arange(0,1,.25)]

# export the data
np.savetxt(r'C:\file.csv',d, fmt='%s', delimiter=",")
```

**In Mathematica**

```
data = Import["C:\\file.csv", "CSV"];

ListContourPlot[data]
```

Output:

[image]

### 2 - Advanced (blocking)

Use a socket to communicate results from Python to Wolfram. We'll use `0MQ` instead of the plain python `TCP` socket. You should install [`pyzmq`](https://pypi.org/project/pyzmq/) (the same library Mathematica uses for `Python` `ExternalEvaluate`)

**In Python**

Now, we'll create a socket and bind your function, so on receiving input, output would be calculated and the result would be sent back.

```python
import zmq

HOST = "127.0.0.1"  # localhost
PORT = 65435  # non-privileged ports are > 1023

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
socket.bind(f"tcp://{HOST}:{PORT}")

with socket:
    while True:
        
        message = socket.recv().decode()
        if message=='quit':
            break

        # print (f"[LOG] Received request: \"{message}\"")

        x,y=message.split(' ')
        x=float(x)
        y=float(y)
        socket.send_string(str(computeSomething(x,y)))
```

**In Mathematica**

We'll connect to the socket and define a connector function:

```
socket = SocketConnect["tcp://127.0.0.1:65435", {"ZMQ", "Request"}]

ClearAll[computeSomething];

computeSomething[x_?NumberQ, y_?NumberQ] := (WriteString[socket, ToString[x] <> " " <> ToString[y]];
  Internal`StringToMReal[ReadString[socket]])
```

Plot:

```
ContourPlot[computeSomething[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  MaxRecursion -> 0, PlotPoints -> 2, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]
```

Output:

[image]

The Python section is running and is waiting for input, so If you're done with your Python side, send `"quit"` to stop that.

```
WriteString[socket, "quit"]
```

And close Mathematica `socket`:

```
Close[socket];
```

### 3 - Advanced (non-blocking)

With my limited knowledge, here is another approach that uses IPython IOLoop.

**In Python**

```python
import zmq
from zmq.eventloop.future import Context
from zmq.eventloop.zmqstream import ZMQStream

HOST = "127.0.0.1"  # localhost
PORT = 65435  # non-privileged ports are > 1023
```

```python
context = Context.instance()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
socket.bind(f"tcp://{HOST}:{PORT}")
stream = ZMQStream(socket)

def temp(message):
    x,y=message.result()[0].decode().split(' ')
    x=float(x)
    y=float(y)
    stream.send_string(str(computeSomething(x,y)))

stream.on_recv(temp)

# ioloop.IOLoop.current().start() is not needed because IPython is already started a loop, so it'll raise error
```

Use `Solution 2` Mathematica code to connect to the server and plot the result.

### Notes:

- I used minimal quality in the `Advance` section and it took on average under `1` second (sometimes the output was not right, re-evaluating will help)
- On higher quality, it'll take a long time to calculate (you can mix the above solutions to create the table inside Mathematica)
- `Internal` `StringToMReal` was used to convert String to Real, it's undocumented and is not guaranteed to work on all versions (in fact it was renamed for consistency)

Comment: This looks good! But it requires the event loop and the call to Mathematica to run synchronously. It would be great to show some code for how to do this (e.g. with `asyncio`).

Comment: @JEM_Mosig Non-blocking method gets added.